# Where to find CATransformLayer examples and documentation

Tags: core-graphics, catransformlayer

Is there anywhere I can read a good tutorial on CATransformLayer?
Apple's documentation seems very brief on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a great one by Mark Pospesel at http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/anatomy-of-a-folding-animation/